# Django DRF role level permission

Tags: django, django-rest-framework, django-rest-auth, django-permissions

I have developed API's using DRF. I am struggling to relate the authorization part from Django's default permission which we define in the admin section for each and every role to the API.

Let's say I have two API's `Customer Management` and `Customer Sales` and have two roles created from them at the Django admin portal. `manager` role will only manage customer (`add`, `view`, `delete` and `update`) whereas `sales` role will manage sales (`add`, `view`, `delete` and `update`) for **every customer**.

When I try testing them in the admin portal the permissions work fine. The corresponding role has corresponding access. If I use the same with REST API it fails to comply with permission which is defined in the backend. It is like both the roles are able to access both the API's.

How do I handle this? Should I implement my own permission system ignoring old one (`auth_permission`, `auth_group_permissions`, `auth_user_user_permissions`) used in Django or is there any workaround to use Django permissions to make this work?

Comment: api_views don't use django's default permissions. have a look at https://www.django-rest-framework.org/api-guide/permissions/#djangomodelpermissions

Comment: So technically i can ignore them and design my own model, is it?

Comment: Yes, but the link I provided shows that you can also use django's default permissions model.

Comment: Okay, which do you suggest to use.. if you had to use angular or react as frontend.. Authorization using default or custom.?

Comment: That is a hard question to answer and varies widely based on use cases. You should note that a major advantage of using built-in django permissions make it easier to edit them using django's admin page, which gives you an off the shelve backoffice. if you re-implement permissions, you would have to add your own management system.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can make your permission class as below

```
class CustomPermission(BasePermission):
    def has_permission(self, request, view):
        if request.user.is_authenticated():
            return True if request.has_perm('can_read') else False # or stuff similar to this 
        return False
```

And use this `CustomPermission` class to your `APIView` 's attribute.

For more information on [DRF permissions](https://www.django-rest-framework.org/api-guide/permissions/) visit https://www.django-rest-framework.org/api-guide/permissions/